# Given a vector $(1, 2, 3 )^T$ wrt to the basis B, what are its coordinates wrt to the basis $\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have a vector, $v$, $ (1,2, 3)^T$ wrt to the basis B and I want to find its coordinates wrt to the basis $\alpha$.

The change of basis matrix, $P_2$ from $\alpha$ to B is given by

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The change of basis matrix, $P_2$ from B to $\alpha$ is given by its inverse which is
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    {1}/{3} & {-2}/{3} & {1}/{3} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    {-1}/{3} & {-1}/{3} & {2}/{3}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The solution given on the worksheet uses $P_1$: $P_1 v$.

However I am confused as this is the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to B. I thought that we would want to use $P_2$ as this changes basis from B to $\alpha$.

The full pdf can be found below under question 1:

[https://math.hawaii.edu/~gautier/change.pdf](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Egautier/change.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$v_B=P v_\alpha \iff P^{-1}v_B=P^{-1}P v_\alpha \iff v_\alpha=P^{-1}v_B$$

with

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \quad P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    {1}/{3} & {-2}/{3} & {1}/{3} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    {-1}/{3} & {-1}/{3} & {2}/{3}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

which agrees with the indication given in the linked paper.

Comment: Sorry not following your notation above. Could you explain further please

Comment: @InvestingScientist $v_B$ represents the vector in base B and $v_\alpha$ in base $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Note what they say in the reminder on the top of page 1: The change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $B$ is the matrix $P_1$ which for any vector $v$, with $\alpha$-representation $[v]_\alpha$, fulfills
$$
[v]_\alpha=P_1[v]_B
$$
So yes, according to that paper, the to and from goes the opposite direction of what you seem to think.

Comment: Sorry but given that our vector i a coordinate vector wrt B, shouldn't we be applying the other matrix?

Comment: @InventingScientist Not according to the naming convention clearly established at the top of your pdf. As I said, it goes the other way of what you seem to think.

Comment: Ok thank you for that. Find it confusing myself but thanks for pointing it out to me

Comment: @InventingScientist I am not a fan of that naming myself. But it is what it is.